# Facebook share using Open Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, facebook-opengraph

I have implemented the FB share using Open Graph and its getting share too.
My problem is when i click to share popup open and shows me "like an object" (See attached).

I have done the following things

```
FB.init({
      appId: 'xxxxx', 
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v2.5'
    });

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'))

FB.ui({
      method: 'share_open_graph',
      action_type: 'og.likes',
      action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object: {
          'og:url': 'URL',
          'og:title': 'Title',
          'og:description': 'description',
          'og:image': 'image'
        }
      })
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response) {
        Vue.$notify('Shared successfully!', 'success')
      }
    })
```

[image]

Comment: What's actually wrong?  That image looks fine to me.  Can you try and explain what you expect and how it's different?

Comment: In the image you can see "like an object". In general need to be show "like an link"

Comment: use og tags on the original url then, instead of that workaround. you ARE actually posting an object right now.

Comment: @luschn, The images which i want to share will be dynamic so cant set the static og tags. And related the object, its a format of FB share. I have also tried to change the name but then it gave me an error

Comment: images of urls should not be dynamic. you need to create a static url for different images.

Comment: Can you please give me an example